# Which Stack Exchange site (or any other site) is suitable to discuss app idea questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am thinking to develop a Chrome App/Extension.

But before implementing my core idea I want to have a quick discussion or suggestion from people about any other key features that I might be missing.

So, now my confusion is on which specific site of [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) shall I write my question?

**My Analysis:**

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)/[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) = No, as I am not seeking "coding doubt"
- [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) = Could Be
- [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) = Could Be  "Prototype & Features Discussion"

---

It would be great to know if there are **any other sites** (other than Stack Exchange sister sites) specifically for such app idea discussions.

Comment: There are no suitable sites, since it will be primarily opinion based & no objective answer, which is off-topic on almost SE sites.

Comment: Ohh.. So what about any other sites ?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't answer that since it's outside of SE scope (and I don't have any idea too, since I never think about it), sorry.

Comment: oh not an issue. anyways thanks for the info.

Comment: The key thing to consider is that when you say "discuss* it becomes a discussion rather than a question for a Q&A site. The SE software is designed to facilitate Q&A and at the same time make discussions hard to have (because they distract from the prime focus of the site). Thus, you are looking for sites that focus more on discussions rather than Q&A.

Answer (score 6):

Not Web Apps. Browser extensions/add-ons are off-topic there, as are programming questions.

Market research would be off-topic for all of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh thanks. So is there any other sites in your list where I can put questions like that

Comment: If there is, it's not the kind of site I spend any time at, so couldn't possibly recommend.